# Converting data type nvarchar with decimal place

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Job Costing report that I am building for a client of mine. Their Chart of Accounts contains a decimal to the tenth place (i.e. 1001.55). I am running into an issue where no matter what I do I can't get the nvarchar to convert to either floating, int or numeric. If I take out the last Where clause where I try to filter by COA 5310 then it runs without issue. What glaring obvious issue am I overlooking? Any help would be appreciated!

```
--Build Equiptment
Create Table tmpEquiptment
(
       [dtmDate] datetime
       ,[iCustID] int
       ,[Amount] money
       ,[COA_Number]  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
Insert into tmpEquiptment
       SELECT dtmDate, iCustID, (Register.Debit - Register.Credit), STR(COA.Number)
       From Register 
       Inner Join COA on Register.AccountID = COA.ID  
       WHERE TranType IN ('Payment', 'Invoice', 'Sale', 'Credit', 'Journal Entry', 'Check', 'Item Receipt', 'Bill', 'Vendor Credit', 'CC Charge', 'CC Credit', 'Deposit', 'Inventory Adjustment', 'Serialized Adjustment') 
       AND Coa.Type in ('Cost of Goods Sold','Expense','Other Expense') 
       AND Isnull(COA.iJobCostingType,0) In (2,3)  
       AND Register.iCustID Is Not Null
       And Register.dtmDate Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       And STR(COA.Number) = 5310
```

--OR--

```
--Build Equiptment
Create Table tmpEquiptment
(
       [dtmDate] datetime
       ,[iCustID] int
       ,[Amount] money
       ,[COA_Number]  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
Insert into tmpEquiptment
       SELECT dtmDate, iCustID, (Register.Debit - Register.Credit), CONVERT(varchar(10), COA.Number)
       From Register 
       Inner Join COA on Register.AccountID = COA.ID  
       WHERE TranType IN ('Payment', 'Invoice', 'Sale', 'Credit', 'Journal Entry', 'Check', 'Item Receipt', 'Bill', 'Vendor Credit', 'CC Charge', 'CC Credit', 'Deposit', 'Inventory Adjustment', 'Serialized Adjustment') 
       AND Coa.Type in ('Cost of Goods Sold','Expense','Other Expense') 
       AND Isnull(COA.iJobCostingType,0) In (2,3)  
       AND Register.iCustID Is Not Null
       And Register.dtmDate Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       And CONVERT(varchar(10), COA.Number) = 5310
```

--OR--

```
--Build Equiptment
Create Table tmpEquiptment
(
       [dtmDate] datetime
       ,[iCustID] int
       ,[Amount] money
       ,[COA_Number]  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
Insert into tmpEquiptment
       SELECT dtmDate, iCustID, (Register.Debit - Register.Credit), CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), COA.Number)
       From Register 
       Inner Join COA on Register.AccountID = COA.ID  
       WHERE TranType IN ('Payment', 'Invoice', 'Sale', 'Credit', 'Journal Entry', 'Check', 'Item Receipt', 'Bill', 'Vendor Credit', 'CC Charge', 'CC Credit', 'Deposit', 'Inventory Adjustment', 'Serialized Adjustment') 
       AND Coa.Type in ('Cost of Goods Sold','Expense','Other Expense') 
       AND Isnull(COA.iJobCostingType,0) In (2,3)  
       AND Register.iCustID Is Not Null
       And Register.dtmDate Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       And CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), COA.Number) = 5310
```

--OR--

```
--Build Equiptment
Create Table tmpEquiptment
(
       [dtmDate] datetime
       ,[iCustID] int
       ,[Amount] money
       ,[COA_Number]  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
Insert into tmpEquiptment
       SELECT dtmDate, iCustID, (Register.Debit - Register.Credit), CAST([COA.Number] AS NVARCHAR(25))
       From Register 
       Inner Join COA on Register.AccountID = COA.ID  
       WHERE TranType IN ('Payment', 'Invoice', 'Sale', 'Credit', 'Journal Entry', 'Check', 'Item Receipt', 'Bill', 'Vendor Credit', 'CC Charge', 'CC Credit', 'Deposit', 'Inventory Adjustment', 'Serialized Adjustment') 
       AND Coa.Type in ('Cost of Goods Sold','Expense','Other Expense') 
       AND Isnull(COA.iJobCostingType,0) In (2,3)  
       AND Register.iCustID Is Not Null
       And Register.dtmDate Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       And CAST([COA.Number] AS NVARCHAR(25)) = 5310
```

Comment: Representing a chart as a decimal sounds like a bad idea to begin with. Clearly whoever had that idea did not have an RDBMS in mind. Why not store them in separate columns, or at least combine with a hyphen? And your issue is that you are casting a decimal value as a string and trying to compare it to an integer. You can't compare '5310.22'  to 5310. You would need to take the LEFT 4 digits or do a string comparison.

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE COA.Number = '5130'`?

Comment: Why are you changing COA.Number's type in a WHERE clause? Use the column's own type for comparison.

Comment: I am using a conversion because if I simply use     WHERE COA.Number = '5130' then it will not run, it throws an error of nvarchar not able to convert to int. Also I agree with you that this numbering system was made up by accountants and not a SQL DBA. I do like the idea of using a left "trim" where it would only capture the first 4 digits.

Comment: Your problem is that your account *STRINGS* are *STRINGS* and you are comparing to an integer. This is why I said it sounded like a bad idea to use decimals for accounting accounts. You have to treat all your "decimals" as strings because they are actually strings and not numbers. Which means now you have to write everything with a cast function and write your decimals as literal strings. Please read what we are telling you.

Comment: What is the actual SQL type of COA.Number?

Comment: Number is nvarchar 20

Comment: Exactly as we are saying, you can't compare a decimal/int to a string. The reason those are strings is because they are *account strings*. Not actually representing numeric values, but representing lines of business and departments as a number. I would highly recommend against using decimals here, but it's your mess to deal with later so do what you please.  @bjones gave you the answer, and that is to use '5130' (string) and not 5130 (int) in your query.

Comment: Thank you Jacob H, I was having a moment of insanity there and thinking that it was a bigger problem than it really was. You are correct @bjones that does return what I need! Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jacob H for the explanation behind bjones answer. This was an issue of simply over engineering a solution when it really was just an ID10T error. One can not use a int (read without quotes) for a String value (with single quotes)

```
--Build Equiptment
Create Table tmpEquiptment
(
       [dtmDate] datetime
       ,[iCustID] int
       ,[Amount] money
       ,[COA_Number]  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
Insert into tmpEquiptment
       SELECT dtmDate, iCustID, (Register.Debit - Register.Credit), COA.Number
       From Register 
       Inner Join COA on Register.AccountID = COA.ID  
       WHERE TranType IN ('Payment', 'Invoice', 'Sale', 'Credit', 'Journal Entry', 'Check', 'Item Receipt', 'Bill', 'Vendor Credit', 'CC Charge', 'CC Credit', 'Deposit', 'Inventory Adjustment', 'Serialized Adjustment') 
       AND Coa.Type in ('Cost of Goods Sold','Expense','Other Expense') 
       AND Isnull(COA.iJobCostingType,0) In (2,3)  
       AND Register.iCustID Is Not Null
       And Register.dtmDate Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       And COA.Number = '5310'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely happens because *some* of the rows in COA.Number are not numeric. You can verify this with the following query:

```
select * from COA where ISNUMERIC(COA.Number) <> 1
```

Now you can either fix those rows, or you can filter them out while creating your new table with the opposite:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(COA.Number) = 1
```

Comment: Good lord don't "fix" the rows. This is an accounting system. You will break the entire business if you round the integers. Unless you are in the process of rewriting the entire COA then just use the string.

Comment: Right, I meant numeric, not integers. Fixed.